# SVD based recommender system C#

Tags: recommender-system, svd, c#

I'm trying to reduce the number of dimensions in my dataset for a movie recommender system using SVD. I'm using the 'MovieLens 1M Dataset' from GroupLens.org. I've used the MathNet library for computing SVD and it seems to work alright.

As far as I know I should be able to input my ratings matrix, compute the SVD of the matrix and then keep the top 80% of the singular values of the Sigma matrix. This should give me the best low rank approximation. I was expecting to get about 10-20 singular values for my dataset to reach 80% of the total singular values. I've tested it with 1000 movies and 1000 users and about 135.000 ratings from the MovieLens Dataset. When I compute the SVD of this and keep the top 80% of the sigma matrix i end up with 289 sigular values (dimensions). What am I doing wrong? Shouldnt I be able to reduce the data to a few dimensions (less than 30)

Can I reduce the number of dimensions more and still keep the precision? I've tried filling all 0 values in the matrix with the avg rating from that specific user, but it didnt have the effect i was looking for. Is there something i need to do with the data before or after running the SVD or is my data simply in ~ 300 dimensions? Do you know any other datasets which might be easier for me to reduce the number of dimensions of.

I'm programming in C# and i've included part of my current code here:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RecommenderSystem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //ConnectDatabase();
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=millionRatings;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

            sqlConnection.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 [MovieID] FROM dbo.Rating ORDER BY MovieID DESC";
            int MaxMovieID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 [UserID] FROM dbo.Rating ORDER BY UserID DESC";
            int MaxUserID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Rating ORDER BY UserID ASC";

            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var elements = new List<Tuple<int, int, double>>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                elements.Add(new Tuple<int, int, double>((int)reader["UserID"] - 1, (int)reader["MovieID"] - 1, (double)reader["Score"]));
            }

            Matrix<double> matrix = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfIndexed(MaxUserID, MaxMovieID, elements);

            Console.WriteLine("Original Matrix:\n" + matrix);

            var _ReducedMatrix = ReducedMatrix(matrix, 1000, 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Reduced Matrix:\n" + _ReducedMatrix);

            var SVD = _ReducedMatrix.Svd(true);

            Console.WriteLine(SVD.U.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine(SVD.W.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine(SVD.VT.ToString("0.00"));

            CalculateEnergy(SVD);

            var FilledMatrix = FillAvgUserRating(_ReducedMatrix);

            Console.WriteLine("Filled Matrix:\n" + FilledMatrix);

            var SVDFilled = FilledMatrix.Svd(true);

            Console.WriteLine(SVDFilled.U.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine(SVDFilled.W.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine(SVDFilled.VT.ToString("0.00"));

            CalculateEnergy(SVDFilled);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }


        public static Matrix<double> ReducedMatrix(Matrix<double> matrix, int rows, int columns)
        {
            var elements = new List<Tuple<int, int, double>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    elements.Add(new Tuple<int, int, double>(i, j, matrix[i, j]));

            return Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfIndexed(rows, columns, elements);
        }

        private static int CalculateEnergy(Svd<double> SVD)
        {
            int conceptCount = SVD.S.Count();
            double TotalEnergy = SVD.S.Sum();

            Console.WriteLine("Total Energy: " + TotalEnergy.ToString("0.00"));

            double rho = 0.80;

            double UsedEnergy = 0;
            int Count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < conceptCount; i++)
            {
                if (UsedEnergy <= (TotalEnergy * rho) || (SVD.S[i] / TotalEnergy * 100 >= 5.0))
                {
                    UsedEnergy += SVD.S[Count];
                    Console.WriteLine("Including #" + (i + 1).ToString("00") + " (" + ((SVD.S[i] / TotalEnergy * 100).ToString("00.00") + "% / " + ((UsedEnergy / TotalEnergy * 100).ToString("00.00")) + " % )"));
                    Count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Including #" + (i + 1).ToString("00") + " (" + ((SVD.S[i] / TotalEnergy * 100).ToString("00.00") + "% )"));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nReturning " + Count + " Concepts!");
            return Count;
        }

        public static Matrix<double> FillAvgUserRating(Matrix<double> matrix)
        {
            var elements = new List<Tuple<int, int, double>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount; i++) // each rows
            {
                // calculate avg of each user
                double sum = 0.0;
                var count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] != 0)
                    {
                        sum += matrix[i, j];
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                double avg = (count == 0 ? 0 : sum / count);

                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] == 0)
                    {
                        elements.Add(new Tuple<int, int, double>(i, j, avg));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        elements.Add(new Tuple<int, int, double>(i, j, matrix[i, j]));
                    }
                }
            }

            return Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfIndexed(matrix.RowCount, matrix.ColumnCount, elements);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone is interested in seeing the console output of the code above, i've uploaded it here: https://justpaste.it/15wgc

Comment: The bases of your expectations are obscure: there is nothing whatsoever in statistical theory that says the largest 10-20 singular values of a matrix (of any size) ought to account for 80% of the total variance.  You seem to be asking more of SVD than it is generally capable of delivering.